# Flip card effect with css3 and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, flip

There are many css3 flip card effect, and there are many jquery plugin that support flip effect.
I want a solution with Modernizr that work in all major browsers.
This solution must work with typical HTML markup:

```
<div class='flip-container'>
   <div class='flipy'>
      <div class='front'></div>
      <div class='back'></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Do you know any solution?

Edit:
Scenario: many profile that appear as thumbnail. When mouse go on profile thumbnail, revert to back and show extra information.
I want to use [flip plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/). jquery implementation like this:

> ```
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         if (!Modernizr.csstransitions) {
>             $('.flip-front').bind("mouseenter", function () {
>                 var elem = $(this);
>
>                 if (elem.data('flipped')) { } else {
>                     elem.flip({
>                         direction: 'lr',
>                         speed: 270,
>                         color: '#000000',
>                         bgColor: 'black',
>                         onBefore: function () {
>                             elem.stop(); /*added but still doesn't work*/
>
>                             elem.html(elem.siblings('.flip-back').html());
>
>                         },
>                         onAnimation: function () {
>                             elem.data('flipped', true);
>
>                         },
>                         onEnd: function () {
>
>                         }
>                     });
>                 }
>             });
>
>             $('.flip-front').bind("mouseleave", function () {
>
>
>
>                 var elem = $(this);
>                 if (elem.data('flipped')) {
>                     elem.flip({
>                         direction: 'rl',
>                         speed: 270,
>                         color: '#000000',
>                         bgColor: 'black',
>                         onBefore: function () {
>                             elem.stop(); /*added but still doesn't work*/
>                             elem.html(elem.siblings('.flip-front').html());
>
>                         },
>                         onAnimation: function () {
>                             elem.data('flipped', false);
>                         },
>                         onEnd: function () {
>
>                         }
>                     });
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>     });
> ```

but above script is not work.

Comment: hover effect is important for me

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question. Consider showing what you've tried and where it went wrong.

Comment: css3 part of solution is clear and exist, remain jquery plugin that must work with above HTML markup